# Having trouble getting my first jquery widget under my belt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to use the following slider
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range
I want to have all of the files local so I can work offline.
Right now all I'm trying to do is get a demo page that displays nothing but this slider.
I believe my struggle is: which js, css files do I need to download/include?  Once I get this first one under my belt I should be off and running.

Thanks for the help.

edit:

So I downloaded the code, put my html file in the directory the rest of the folders are in and I get nothing.  To be extra clear.  I have a folder with my HTML file, css, development-bundle and js folder in it.  Here's my code: The script was grabbed from the jquery demo.  I'm sure I'm making this WAYYYY more complicated than it needs to be.  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [ 75, 300 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="demo">

<p>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors showing in your web console?

Comment: Fyi, the recent jQuery versions are `1.6.4` and `1.7`.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript in your script tag is executing before the html in your body tag, so jQuery can't resolve those selectors. Try waiting for the DOM to load before executing your JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //  $( "#slider-range" ) ...
    // $( "#amount" )...
});
```

Fwiw, for small projects like this I almost always start with an alert("test") or console.log("test") inside this document ready function. It's a quick and easy way to tell if your libraries are loading and your JS is executing properly from the start.

Comment: Don't you see this? `$(function() {`